# Kentico Form - 2 Columns and responsive for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, forms, kentico

I have created a Form in Kentico which I want to use on a full page for registration.

The issue I have is that the form is only displaying as one column, there is a lot of space remaining to the right of the form, so ideally I would like the form to sit over 2 columns. BUT, I need it to reformat itself for the screen size.

I have tried Custom and Auto Generated Layouts, but no joy with either, I have also tried adding a table with 2 columns to achieve what I want, this works fine on desktop, but when displaying on mobile, the user is presented with a horizontal scrollbar, so not a great experience.

Please can someone point me in the right direction with this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve can be done with the proper use of CSS or, more often, with the use of some front-end framework to do the work for you.

For example, Bootstrap can do forms very easily - [see](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) for yourself.

There are many other frameworks you can use instead of Bootstrap such as Semantic-ui, Foundation or Material to name a few. Take a look [here](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/front-end-frameworks/) for more examples.

Now, for the integration with Kentico - you will need to use Custom layout and follow the HTML/syntax from the given framework & you will of course need to include the styles/js on your master page. Thats pretty much it :-)

Comment: Just adding in, it won't be "Custom Layout" it will just be "Layout" on the Form tab (which you'll of course customize), but know editing the "Layout" will also edit the internal form layout, so i usually recommend you go to "Alternative Forms" and create an alternative form, then in there you would create the Layout and use that, that way it won't affect the CMS view of the form!

Comment: agreed :-) better to create custom objects if you can.